# Form of an operator to get a Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In some math notes that I have it is defined an operator $\mathbf{R}$ such as an operator that converts a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ into the matrix

$
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}(1) & \mathbf{x}(2) & ... & \mathbf{x}(P)\\
\mathbf{x}(2) & \mathbf{x}(3) & ... & \mathbf{x}(P+1)\\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
\mathbf{x}(N-P+1) & \mathbf{x}(N-P+2) & ... & \mathbf{x}(N)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $P$ is and arbitrary chosen integer such as $P\leq N$ and $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{(N-P+1)\times P}$. So, the operator it used as $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{Rx}$. After, some calculations it is also used the transpose of the operator, that is, $\mathbf{R}^T$.

My question is, what is this operator? And its transpose? It seems like a matrix but it cannot be.

Thanks!

Comment: it is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to  $\mathbb{R}^{(N-P+1)\times P}$ which can be expressed as a matrix if you think to the resulting matrix as a vector, or as a tensor. it is of the same type as the operator which converts a vector to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not get the idea yet. Could you further explain it?